ITK histogram unable to correctly set lower value
I have an ITK image of type using ITKImage = itk::Image<short, 3>; that I know only has a certain number of values inside, i.e. only values 0,1,..., n. For the sake of argument, let's assume n=2, so the image values are only 0, 1 or 2. I want to count the number of times each value, except 0, appears in the image, which I tried to do with the histogram filter. I do the following:
//////////////////////////////////
// Code to produce variable image of type ITKImage...
//////////////////////////////////
using HistogramFilterType = itk::Statistics::ImageToHistogramFilter<ITKImage>;
auto histogramFilter = HistogramFilterType::New();
using SizeType = HistogramFilterType::HistogramSizeType;
SizeType size(1);
size[0] = 2;

HistogramFilterType::HistogramMeasurementVectorType lowerBound(1);
lowerBound[0] = 1;
HistogramFilterType::HistogramMeasurementVectorType upperBound(1);
upperBound[0] = 2;

histogramFilter->SetHistogramBinMinimum(lowerBound);
histogramFilter->SetHistogramBinMaximum(upperBound);

histogramFilter->SetHistogramSize(size);
histogramFilter->SetInput(objectFilter->GetOutput());
histogramFilter->Update();
const unsigned int histogramSize = histogramFilter->GetOutput()->Size();
for (unsigned int bin = 0; bin < histogramSize; ++bin) {
    std::cout << histogramFilter->GetOutput()->GetFrequency(bin) << "\n";
}

Unfortunatelly, this produces strange results. The value GetFrequency(1) correctly returns the number of times 2 appears in the image, but GetFrequency(0) returns the number of times 1 or 0 appears in the image, which is not what I want. Where am I going wrong with configuring the filter?

You probably want to change ClipBinsAtEnds from defaults, see itk::Histogram docs. Possibly like histogramFilter->GetOutput()-> SetClipBinsAtEnds(true); // or maybe false?
